# replace multiple values in the same column as transformation with SSiS

Tags: ssis, transform, integration, data-cleaning

I have a data set with country column , the countries with the there codes but i need to replace this codes with the actual names , I am trying the derived column transform but it
only accept on values to replace it
any ideas  ?

[1] https://i.stack.imgur.com/imv2m.png]

Comment: what do you mean by 'it only accepts on values to replace'? what did you expect/need? If you need to convert only a few codes, you can use a conditional operator `«boolean_expression» ? «when_true» : «when_false»` but if lots of country codes, then you can use the  `lookup` component (then the code-name data should come from a source with OLEDB connection). Also beware, the derived column replacing the original column can't increase its length.

Comment: i already found a solution by using C# transformation script to change multiple values in the same column use a dictionary array and for each condition to search and replace